# why custom directives inside ng-repeat run after the loop is complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular and I've found myself having lots of issue with understanding the order of things in Angular.

Currently my issue is that I would like to run my directives(total-for-one-entry) for every object inside ng-repeat. I have got the following view:

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="user in weekTimesheet.currentTimeSheet.users">
                                <tr>

                                    <th class="timesheets-employee" rowspan="{{ user.numberOfVisibleDays + user.totalNumberOfEntries +  2 }}">
                                        <strong>{{ user.firstName }}</strong><br>
                                        <small>
                                            <strong ng-repeat="position in user.positions">{{ user.position }}</strong>
                                        </small>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>


                            <tr ng-repeat-start="day in user.days" ng-if="day.tsEntries.length !== 0">
                                <th class="record-date" rowspan="{{ day.tsEntries.length + 1}}">
                                    {{ day.dayName }} {{day.daysDate | amDateFormat:'DD/MM'}}
                                </th>

                            </tr>


                            <tr ng-repeat-start="tsEntry in day.tsEntries" ng-if="day.tsEntries.length !==0">
                                <td><strong>{{ tsEntry.type }}</strong></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="record-main">
                                        {{tsEntry.tsStart.tsStartTime}}
                                        <input type="text" ng-class="{focused : tsEntry.tsStart.inEditMode, blured: tsEntry.tsStart.inReadMode}" ng-model="tsEntry.tsStart.tsStartTime" ng-model-of-time ng-focus="swapReadAndEditModes(tsEntry)" ng-blur="swapReadAndEditModes(tsEntry)"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="record-sub">
                                        <span class="record-journal"><i class="icon-interface-clock"></i> {{ tsEntry.tsStart.tsJournalStartTime | amDateFormat: 'HH:MM'}}</span>
                                        <span class="record-clock"><i class="icon-interface-stopwatch"></i> {{ tsEntry.tsStart.tsTaStartTime | amDateFormat: 'HH:MM'}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="record-main">
                                        {{tsEntry.tsEnd.tsEndTime}}
                                        <input type="text" ng-class="{focused : tsEntry.tsEnd.inEditMode, blured: tsEntry.tsEnd.inReadMode}" ng-model="tsEntry.tsEnd.tsEndTime" ng-model-of-time ng-focus="swapReadAndEditModes(tsEntry)" ng-blur="swapReadAndEditModes(tsEntry)"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="record-sub">
                                        <span class="record-journal"><i class="icon-interface-clock"></i> {{ tsEntry.tsEnd.tsJournalEndTime | amDateFormat: 'HH:MM'}}</span>
                                        <span class="record-clock"><i class="icon-interface-stopwatch"></i> {{ tsEntry.tsEnd.tsTaEndTime | amDateFormat: 'HH:MM'}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="record-main">
                                        {{tsEntry.tsBreak.tsBreakDur}}
                                        <input type="number" min="0" max="999" ng-class="{focused : tsEntry.tsBreak.inEditMode, blured: tsEntry.tsBreak.inReadMode}" ng-model-of-time ng-model="tsEntry.tsBreak.tsBreakDur" ng-focus="swapReadAndEditModes(tsEntry)" ng-blur="swapReadAndEditModes(tsEntry)"/>m
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="record-sub">
                                        <span class="record-journal"><i class="icon-interface-clock"></i> {{ tsEntry.tsBreak.tsJournalBreakTime}}m</span>
                                        <span class="record-clock"><i class="icon-interface-stopwatch"></i> {{ tsEntry.tsBreak.tsTaBreakTime }}m</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div total-for-one-entry tsEntry="tsEntry"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <div total-for-one-entry tsEntry="tsEntry"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>{{tsEntry.note}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="btn mini green" href="#">Approve</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="true"></tr>
                            <tr ng-repeat-end ng-hide="true"></tr>

</tbody>
```

This is my directive:

```
timesheetsModule.directive('totalForOneEntry', ['Calculator', function (Calculator) {


    var getDuration = function (tsEntry) {
        var duration;

            if (tsEntry.type == "Shift") {
                duration = Calculator.getTsOrJournalOrTaShiftOrLeaveHours(tsEntry.tsStart.tsStartTime,tsEntry.tsEnd.tsEndTime,tsEntry.tsBreak.tsBreakDur);
                tsEntry.tsShiftHours = duration;

            } else {
                duration = Calculator.getTsOrJournalOrTaShiftOrLeaveHours(tsEntry.tsStart.tsStartTime, tsEntry.tsEnd.tsEndTime, 0);
                tsEntry.tsLeaveHours = duration;
            }


            if (tsEntry.tsStart.journal) {
                if (tsEntry.tsStart.journal.type == "Shift") {
                    duration = Calculator
                        .getTsOrJournalOrTaShiftOrLeaveHours(tsEntry.tsStart.tsJournalStartTime,
                            tsEntry.tsEnd.tsJournalEndTime,
                            tsEntry.tsBreak.tsJournalBreakTime);

                    tsEntry.journalShiftHours = duration;
                } else {
                    duration = Calculator
                        .getTsOrJournalOrTaShiftOrLeaveHours(tsEntry.tsStart.tsJournalStartTime,
                            tsEntry.tsEnd.tsJournalEndTime,
                            0);
                    tsEntry.journalLeaveHours = duration;
                }


            }

            if (tsEntry.tsStart.timeAndAttendance) {
                duration = Calculator.getTsOrJournalOrTaShiftOrLeaveHours(tsEntry.tsStart.tsTaStartTime, tsEntry.tsEnd.tsTaEndTime, tsEntry.tsBreak.tsTaBreakTime);
                tsEntry.taShiftHours = duration;
            }


    };

    return {

        restrict: "A",
        scope: { tsEntry: "=" },
        replace:"true",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            console.log($scope.tsEntry);
            getDuration($scope.tsEntry);

        },
        templateUrl: "Scripts/Timesheet/Templates/totalForOneEntry.html"

    };
}]);
```

And finally the following is my template:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div class="record-main">{{tsEntry.type === "shift" ? tsEntry.tsShiftHours:tsEntry.tsLeaveHours}} hrs</div>
        <div class="record-sub">
            <span class="record-journal"><i class="icon-interface-clock"></i>{{tsEntry.type === "shift" ? tsEntry.journalShiftHours:tsEntry.journalLeaveHours}} hrs</span>
            <span class="record-clock" ng-if="tsEntry.type == 'Shift'"><i class="icon-interface-stopwatch"></i> {{tsEntry.taShiftHours}} hrs</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem here is that, Angular processes everything except my direcrectives, and for some reason once ng-repeat is finished it decides to run the directives but now tsEntry attribute that I passed to directive is undefined.

I would appreciate if someone could give me a hand. 
Cheers.

Comment: Don't you require a link function? Try adding a linking function to your directive.

Comment: Oh ho ho .... There is no compile, no pre, no post, no controller - how do u suppose your directive to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

```
 <div total-for-one-entry ts-entry="tsEntry"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div total-for-one-entry tsEntry="tsEntry"></div>
```